# Getting your script to run repeatedly at intervals?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on an extension that retrieves tweets and I want it to do this at certain intervals, but after reading Google's [Content Security Policy Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#relaxing-eval) it seems it is no longer possible to simply use:

```
setInterval(someFunction, interval);
```

So how would one go about doing this?

Comment: That document seems to talk about the `setInterval(String)` version - the important thing is the `String` is a concern (because in a way, it is `eval`ed...the point of the policy). Passing a Function doesn't seem to be covered by this. So if you're actually referring to (and implementing) passing a String, you should be able to easily change it to pass a Function (which is better to do anyways). For example, instead of `setInterval("someFunc()", 5000);`, you can use `setInterval(someFunc, 5000);`

Comment: I am passing a function and not a string when using it, so there must be another reason why my script does not seem to be repeating :/

Comment: Well then post your code and explain the problem. Your question was specifically about the Policy, and nothing about specific code not working

Comment: Yeah which is why I'm not posting the code, I will look further into my problem and if I don't solve it I will post another question. But thank you for the help on this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google's Content Security Policy prevents you passing a string as the first argument in `setInterval`. You should have no problem passing a function.

The reason for this is they want to avoid evaluated JavaScript. Passing a function as a string forces that string to be evaluated similar to using `eval()`. See [this previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) on why `eval()` can be a security issue.